# How to fix VSCode intellisense in fresh .vue files?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

There is no autoimports, component tips and etc in .vue files just created (1st screen). If i restart VSCode it's immediatly appears (2nd screen), but still doesn't work in new files. So i have to restart VS Code every new .vue file to have the stuff.

My extensions are:

- IntelliCode
- TypeScript Hero
- Volar (with TakeOver mode enabled)
- Vue VSCode Snippets

Maybe someone has encountered a similar problem and knows how to solve it?

[image]

[image]